# Am I using FragmentPagerAdapter correctly?

Tags: android, fragment

`getItem()`, am I create fragment everytime?

and what is the good example for make fragmentActivity with FragmentPagerAdapter?

I'm so sorry for ask question fooly...

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) 
        {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.


            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                Fragment fragment_tab1 = new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_02(getApplicationContext());
                fragment_tab1.setRetainInstance(true);

                return fragment_tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment fragment_tab2 = new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_01(getApplicationContext());
                fragment_tab2.setRetainInstance(true);
                return fragment_tab2;
            case 2:
                Fragment fragment_tab3 =  new MainActivity_Fragment_Tab_03(getApplicationContext());
                fragment_tab3.setRetainInstance(true);
                return fragment_tab3;

            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems alright, is it not working as expected? The getItem() will be called one time from the viewpager, then it will keep the fragment in memory so it will not have to call it more then once.

One thing I would change is to move:

```
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
```

to

```
        default:
```

last in the switch case, to make the code more efficient.

To know more there is a good example here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: Np! If you are satisfied with the answer please upvote it and/or mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static count and you know that it won't change, such as tabs in your activity, you should use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will keep your fragments in memory when they are viewed, view hierarchy might be destroyed when needed.

`FragmentPagerAdapter` is used for dynamic content and each time you swipe and get another fragment, fragment will be destroyed but state will be stored.